# how to cross compile zthread for ios 5.1

Tags: ios5.1, cross-compiling

how to cross compile zthread for ios 5.1 , any one can help me ?

http://www.cnblogs.com/maadiah/archive/2012/04/06/2434591.html
and
http://www.haogongju.net/art/1382733

i try the links way , but fail  with this error.

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/iphone --build=arm-apple-darwin10 --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc  CFLAGS="-arch armv7 -pipe -mdynamic-no-pic -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O2 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=3.2 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk" CPP=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-g++-4.2 AR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar LDFLAGS="-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=3.2"

got the errorlog :
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.9~22/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.9~22/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
llvm-g++-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
configure:2222: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables

all log is :

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced this error for another project. It's because now Xcode 4.3 became an app installed in the /Applications folder (and no more under /Developer)  and all paths changed.
First: did you install the Xcode Command-Line tools? You can verify it opening the menu "XCode-->Preferences-->Downloads".
After having installed them, you should find all the compiler commands under:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/